# Youtube API V3 difficulty

Tags: api, youtube, google-api, google-data-api

I'm trying to fetch playlist's details using Youtube API V3. In documentation says that there is maximum limit for videos for api calls. It's 50 per call. But there is another way to paginate playlist using tokens provided in api callback.

Trying to get `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` from api call result. Using this page as playground https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list . You can check this page using youtube playlist id `PLWNXn_iQ2yrLNCKeW9Pogt_5_3I8ocrm4`. It returns result with no `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken`

Currently my api call url is looking like that:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLWNXn_iQ2yrLNCKeW9Pogt_5_3I8ocrm4&maxResults=50&fields=items%2Fsnippet&key=my-api-key`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the fields parameter you have specified only **items/snippet**, so no pagination in response. Change it to something like this:

```
items/snippet,nextPageToken,prevPageToken,tokenPagination
```

so that your api url looks like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLWNXn_iQ2yrLNCKeW9Pogt_5_3I8ocrm4&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2CnextPageToken%2CprevPageToken%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the fields parameter, so your call looks like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLWNXn_iQ2yrLNCKeW9Pogt_5_3I8ocrm4
```

Done this way, `nextPageToken` will be included in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=50&channelId={{CHANNEL ID}}&key={{API KEY}}